# How do i validate email and mobile number using single input field in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Email validation is worked now for me using below code and now i want to also add Mobile number validation to the same code because user enter his mobile number or email address.

### register.html

```
<md-input-container flex md-no-float>
   <input ng-model="vm.form.email" type="text" placeholder="Email or Mobile Number" translate translate-attr-placeholder="REGISTER.EMAIL" name="email" ng-pattern="vm.regex"  required="true">
   <div ng-messages="regForm.email.$error" ng-show="regForm.email.$touched">
     <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
     <div ng-message="pattern">Your email address is invalid</div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
```

### registerController.js

```
vm.regex = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/;
```

Now i have regular expression for Indian mobile number but i don't know to add with email regular expression and what should i change in my html.

Comment: you can create 2 `<md-input-container>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just connect them with an `OR (|)` statement.

e.g. `/^(emailPattern|phonePattern)$/`

Comment: I connected like that you said but validation always saying your email address is invalid if you enter either email or mobile number.

Comment: Could you provide your current regex?

Comment: vm.regex = /^([a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5} | (?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9})$/;

Comment: I just entered that regex in [some online regex validator](https://regex101.com/) and it worked perfectly fine.